# Dynamically generated list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could anyone give me an idee on how could I generate dynamically this piece od code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server">
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="testingPurposes">
  <li> 
    <div> 
        <span class="text-left" onclick="fct1()"> Text nr 1</span> 
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="myImg.png" runat="server" onclick="fct2()"/> 
    </div> 
  </li>
  <li> 
    <div> 
        <span class="text-left" onclick="fct1()"> Text nr 2 </span> 
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="myImg.png" runat="server" onclick="fct2()"/> 
    </div> 
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The main idea of this code is to have some kind of dropdown list looking control that would have a span with text, and an image on each row.

This is basicly how my control shoud look when it's clicked:

Text1        img1

Text2 img2

If a user clicks TextN i get an event for that click, and i can update the page based on selected item.
If a user clicks imgN then TextN and imgN would disappear from the list.

Comment: Use a `UserControl` which can contain any controls or HTML. Use events to communicate from your UC to your Page.

Comment: i see, thanks. Do you know if it is possible to add a user control as element of drop down list by any chance?

Comment: No, that's not possible. A `DropDownList` is rendered as html-`select` which cannot contain custom controls. Maybe you have to use a different approach or control (like a web-databound control as `GridView`, `Repeater` or `DataList`).

Comment: I would probably do a repeater in this case. You can use bootstrap to make the repeater look like the way you want it.